# How to get port a process is listening on in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

As several blogposts and Stackoverflow answers suggest, it is trivial to get this information via a combination of `get-process` and `Get-NetTCPConnection` commandlets. It is possible to execute these commands via .net code, parse the output and retrieve the information.

Is it not possible to get the port number a process is listening on in pure .net code using just the .net libraries? `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesByName` returns a ton of information via the `Process` object, except for the port the process is listening on.

Any leads highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a TCP socket or UDP? Is it IPv4 or IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()` does not return any information on which process is holding the socket, as it uses `GetTcpTable` not [`GetTcpTable2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2).

You would need to code it yourself. The below code works for TCP over IPv4. You would need similar code for UDP and IPv6.

```cs
[DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int GetTcpTable2(
  IntPtr TcpTable,
  ref int SizePointer,
  bool Order
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MIB_TCPTABLE
{
    public int dwNumEntries;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MIB_TCPROW2
{
    public MIB_TCP_STATE dwState;
    public int dwLocalAddr;
    public byte localPort1;
    public byte localPort2;
    // Ports are only 16 bit values (in network WORD order, 3,4,1,2).
    // There are reports where the high order bytes have garbage in them.
    public byte ignoreLocalPort3;
    public byte ignoreLocalPort4;
    public int dwRemoteAddr;
    public byte remotePort1;
    public byte remotePort2;
    // Ports are only 16 bit values (in network WORD order, 3,4,1,2).
    // There are reports where the high order bytes have garbage in them.
    public byte ignoreremotePort3;
    public byte ignoreremotePort4;
    public int dwOwningPid;
    public TCP_CONNECTION_OFFLOAD_STATE dwOffloadState;
}

public enum MIB_TCP_STATE
{
    Closed = 1,
    Listen,
    SynSent,
    SynRcvd,
    Established,
    FinWait1,
    FinWait2,
    CloseWait,
    Closing,
    LastAck,
    TimeWait,
    DeleteTcb
}

enum TCP_CONNECTION_OFFLOAD_STATE
{
    TcpConnectionOffloadStateInHost,
    TcpConnectionOffloadStateOffloading,
    TcpConnectionOffloadStateOffloaded,
    TcpConnectionOffloadStateUploading,
    TcpConnectionOffloadStateMax
}
```

```cs
static List<IPEndPoint> GetSocketsForProcess(int pid, MIB_TCP_STATE state = MIB_TCP_STATE.Established)
{
    const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A;

    var size = 0;
    var result = GetTcpTable2(IntPtr.Zero, ref size, false);
    if (result != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        throw new Win32Exception(result);
        
    var ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        result = GetTcpTable2(ptr, ref size, false);
        if (result != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(result);

        var list = new List<IPEndPoint>();
        var count = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
        var curPtr = ptr + Marshal.SizeOf<MIB_TCPTABLE>();
        var length = Marshal.SizeOf<MIB_TCPROW2>();
        for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var row = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MIB_TCPROW2>(curPtr);
            if(row.dwOwningPid == pid && row.dwState == state)
                list.Add(new IPEndPoint(row.dwLocalAddr, row.localPort1 << 8 | row.localPort2));
            curPtr += length;
        }
        return list;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the `MIB_TCPROW2` struct definition differ from the one here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tcpmib/ns-tcpmib-mib_tcprow2 ? The code works but the port numbers do not correspond to what I see via TcpView

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9dfdfbf1718c29f4c905bb6474e214fac9fe7910/src/libraries/Common/src/Interop/Windows/IpHlpApi/Interop.NetworkInformation.cs#L394 and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.NetworkInformation/src/System/Net/NetworkInformation/SystemTcpConnection.cs Sorry mistakenly, put the remote port not the local one.

Comment: thanks for the reference. I sorted out the local v/s remote but the numbers I see do not correspond to what I see in TCPView. For ex. TCPView reports port as 9156 but code reports byte value of 35 which after << 8 becomes 8960

Comment: It appears to be a glitch in VSCode debugger. Code works as expected when run without debugging.

Comment: I think the code has a bug. In finally `ptr` is being freed but `ptr` is being advanced in the loop. And it appears to crash the program on subsequent calls. I think we need to hold onto the original pointer to free it in finally.

Comment: Should be fixed now, you're right I was freeing the wrong pointer

Comment: .NET 4.7.2  change the type of `dwLocalAddr` and `dwRemoteAddr` to `uint` from `int` inside `struct MIB_TCPROW2` definition.

Comment: `IPEndpoint` constructor accepts `int` not `uint` so it made life easier. It's the same number of bits and will make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task not long ago. Here is complete .NET 6 code that you should be able to adopt for your particular needs:

```
public static int CheckConnection(string[] servers)
{
    try
    {
        var srvs = servers.ToDictionary(k => k.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1], v => false);

        IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

        IPEndPoint[] endPoints = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnections = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

        var count = 0;
        foreach (var info in tcpConnections)
        {
            var ep = string.Format("{0}:{1}", info.RemoteEndPoint.Address, info.RemoteEndPoint.Port);

            if (info.State.ToString().ToUpper() != "ESTABLISHED")
                continue;

            if (srvs.ContainsKey(ep))
            {
                count++;
                srvs[ep] = true;
            }
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var kvp in srvs)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0,-21}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value ? "OK" : "FAIL");
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        Program.logger.Trace($"ZMQF. Connection check:\n{sb}");

        return count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Program.logger.Fatal(ex, $"ZMQF. CheckConnection exception. Servers: {(string.Join(",", servers))}");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `info.State.ToString().ToUpper() != "ESTABLISHED"` why not just compare the enum value directly?

Comment: no point. that how i did it and it worked. i didnt know this enum existed. if you think enum is better write your own answer. please dont edit other people code. if you see a mistake in English thats fine. but changing code is not nice.

Comment: Not sure how you couldn't see it existed, you are accessing it already in `info.State` and then stringifying it. Pretty reasonable code edit, but if you want to leave it then have it your way.

Comment: @BoppityBop I am assuming your function is trying to determine if a connection has been established on a known port to a known server's IP address, right? What I am trying to determine is that a process (whose name is known) is listening on a given port.